# How to convert working jquery 1.7.2 code into jquery 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code works fine in jquery 1.7.2 but does not in jquery 1.3.2

```
$(".selectallItem8CheckBox").click(function () {
        $(".checkboxItem8select").prop("checked", $(".selectallItem8CheckBox").prop("checked"))
    });
```

Alternative to this would help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific about how it does not work.

Comment: Use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()`

Comment: used attr() instead of prop(). It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.attr()` instead of `.prop()` for jquery 1.5 and below versions:

```
$('.checkboxItem8select').attr('checked',$(".selectallItem8CheckBox").attr("checked"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`.prop()` wasn't added til 1.6. Use `.attr()` instead